# Create tableview with rounded images

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios6

I want to create a UITableview with rounded images from the user.
I have created one tableview with a different label, but I want a round shape image and to display it cell by cell.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need a custom UITableViewCell, with UIImageView* as a property of that cell.

For example, my custom cell's name is MainTableViewCell, and the property is named cellImage:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

static NSString* cellDescriptor = @"customCell";

- (MainTableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellDescriptor];

    MPMediaItemArtwork* artwork = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    // Customise this line, get an image as you like.
    cell.cellImage.image = [artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];

    // These two lines makes image in round shape.
    cell.cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellImage.frame.size.height / 2;
    cell.cellImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Here is an image for the custom cell:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> at top of the controller .m

Comment: Quite right. But the weird thing is, I'm currently using without importing QuartzCore.

Comment: You must had imported QuartzCore somewhere in you project.